# Named capture groups from command line

Tags: macos, bash, shell, regex, perl

I've come up with the following regular expression:

```
\[release(\s+(?<release_type>.*))?\]\n+(?<release_notes>.*)
```

The idea is to parse a commit message for several params:

```
[release minor]

Hello world

- asd
- zxc
```

Matching should result `release_type = 'minor'`, `release_notes = 'Hello world\n…`.

I'm trying to use perl due to old regex engines in macOS.

I've tried:

```
perl -e 'print "$+{release_notes}" while /\[release(\s+(?<release_type>.*))?\]\n+(?<release_notes>.*)/gs;' msg.txt
```

But for some reason, this expression doesn't work as expected.

In fact, even the simpler

```
perl -ne 'print "$+{release_notes}" while /\n(?<release_notes>.*)/gs;' msg.txt
```

fails.

This

```
perl -ne 'print "$+{release_notes}" while /(?<release_notes>.*)/gs;' msg.txt
```

succeeds and just returns the whole input.

I'm probably missing something simple here, but not sure what it is.

Comment: Please, don't [cross post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56831328/372239)

Comment: @Toto Thanks. Any reason why this is disallowed when there is such a big overlap in topics?

Comment: Have a look at: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: Didn’t see a compelling reason there. Anyway, won’t argue about it here.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56487100/983912) game me a solution: adding `-0777` to the command fixes the problem.

To quote:

> It still needs that even as the [`-0777`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) unsets the [input record separator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$/), so the file is read at once; see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582501/why-use-the-p-n-in-slurp-mode-in-perl-one-liner/37583183#37583183